# error with using intel aes API

Tags: c, eclipse, api, aes, static-libraries

I am using eclipse CDT in ubuntu OS. I have an API (Intel-Aes NI) that I am working on. I had run the shell file (mk_lnx64_all.sh) to build the API and get the library(.a file). The library file generated is in folder: /path/to/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/lib/x64/. And I need to run a source file named aessample.c which has main() from folder: /path/to/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/src/ . I added the path and the library name as intel_aes64 (without .a extension) in eclipse settings. But when i build the project still it gives error as:

```
 make all 
Building target: Intel
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/lib/x64 -o "Intel"  ./src/aessample.o ./src/intel_aes.o   -lintel_aes64
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lintel_aes64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Intel] Error 1
```

I tried executing with terminal also with the following command :

```
gcc -I/home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/include intel_aes.c -L/home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/lib/x64 -lintel_aes64
```

even the above command gives error as :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lintel_aes64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I am unable to figure out how to download it from internet and install it with command : apt-get install xxx-dev to get the library installed in /usr/local/lib . where am I doing wrong? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that I have to

**manually rename the file generated by the make/shell/executable file from "intel_aes64.a" to "libintel_aes64.a"**

and then to make it work in eclipse, add its path and library name as "intel_aes64" (asusual by excluding lib-prefix and .a extension).  Since compiler considers only files that start with "lib" as library files.

Answer (score 1):

`-lname` is an abbreviation for `libname.a` (or other library suffixes, such as `libname.dylib`). To use a library file that does not begin with `lib`, simply specify a path to it, the same as you would do with a source file or object file. (In this case, you do not need the `-L` either, as that specifies paths to be searched when `-l` is used.) So you could use this command:

```
gcc -I/home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/include intel_aes.c /home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/lib/x64/intel_aes64.a
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply......I tried compiling the command provided by you, but it still gives error as:

xxx@ubuntu:~/workspace/AES-NI/src$ gcc -I/home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/include intel_aes.c /home/xxx/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/lib/x64/intel_aes64.a

gcc: error: intel_aes.c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /home/Anvesh/Documents/Intel_AESNI_Sample_Library_v1.2/intel_aes_lib/lib/x64/intel_aes64.a: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: @annunarcist: You will need to use the correct paths for your system.